# how to parse a text file for a particular compound expressions filtering in shell scripting

Tags: regex, shell, awk

I want to extract (parse) a text file which has particular word, for my requirement whatever the rows which have the words "cluster" and "week" and "8.2" it should be written to the output file.

### sample text in the file

```
2013032308470272~800000102507~Cluster-Mode~WEEK~8.1.2~V6240
2013032308470272~800000102507~Cluster-Mode~monthly~8.1.2~V6240
2013032308470272~800000102507~Cluster-Mode~WEEK~8.2.2~V6240
2013032308470272~800000102507~Cluster-Mode~yearly~8.1.2~V6240
```

### Desired output into another text file by above mentioned filters

```
2013032308470272~800000102507~Cluster-Mode~WEEK~8.2.2~V6240
```

I have writen a code using the awk command, however the output file contains the rows which are out of the scope of the filters.

### code used to extract the text

```
awk '/Cluster/ && /WEEK/ && /8.2/ { print $NF > "/u/nbsvc/Data/Lookup/derived_asup_2010404_201409_2.txt" }' /u/nbsvc/Data/Lookup/cmode_asup_lookup.txt
```

### obtained output

```
2013032308470272~800000102507~Cluster-Mode~WEEK~8.1.2~V6240
2013032308470272~800000102507~Cluster-Mode~WEEK~8.2.2~V6240
```

Note: the first line of obtained output is not needed in the desired output. How can I change my script to only get the line that I want?

Comment: Your  command works for me. `8.2` -> 8 any char 2. Second line only satisfies this condition.

Comment: @AvinashRaj no all of the input lines contain `8.2` because they all start with `2013032308470272` which contains `847` which matches `8.2` since `.` means `any character`. So then awk just has to find the subset of lines that also contain `Cluster` and `WEEK` and it does find the 2 lines that match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove any ambiguity and false matches on partial fields or the wrong field, THIS is the command you need to run:

```
$ awk -F'~' '$3~/^Cluster/ && $4=="WEEK" && $5~/^8\.2/' file
2013032308470272~800000102507~Cluster-Mode~WEEK~8.2.2~V6240
```

Comment: there is actually little more in my requirement, it is I need to read this text file, then I need to split the line (where the cursor is) and push the values into a array and then I need to check for the values does it match with my pattern or not, if it matches then I need to write it to a out put text file, else simply ignore it, this one I did like as below.. 

cat /inputfolder_path/lookup_filename.txt | awk '{IGNORECASE = 1;line=$0;split(line,a, "~") ;if (a[1] ~ /201404/ && a[3]~/Cluster/ && a[4]~/WEEK/ && a[5]~/8.2/){print $0}}' > /outputfolder_path/derived_output_filename.txt

Comment: @user3094037 If you have more detail to add, you should edit your question rather than commenting beneath someone's answer.

Comment: @user3094037 the script you posted in your comment is completely wrong in several ways, please re-examine the answers you've been given and THINK about it and then if you need to do something else, I'd recommend you post a new question but do not use the script from your comment.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that awk is needed at all here. Just use grep to match the line that you're interested in:

```
grep 'Cluster.*WEEK.*8\.2' file > output_file
```

The `.*` matches zero or more of any character and `>` is used to redirect the output to a new file. I have escaped the `.` in between "8.2" so that it is interpreted literally, rather than matching any character (although it would work either way).

Comment: thanks a lot dude, i tested all the three inputs
I found
awk with character sets 8[.]2 has given good accuracy.
awk with escape (back slash "\") 8\.2 not that much accuracy.

finally the grep, it was awesome in performance, took only 39 seconds whereas the other two options more than a minute (approximately 100 seconds each) but it is similar in accuracy to escape.(back slash)

any how my goal is cleared.. 

thanks a lot again dude..

Comment: @user3094037 you talk about some REs not having much accuracy. The REs are accurate so therefore it's your input that isn't exactly as you showed/expected. For example the given `grep` command will print lines like `2013032308470272~800000102507~Cluster-Mode~WEEK~7.8.2~V6240` which is probably not what you intended, is it?

Answer (score -1):

there is actually little more in my requirement, it is I need to read this text file, then I need to split the line (where the cursor is) and push the values into a array and then I need to check for the values does it match with my pattern or not, if it matches then I need to write it to a out put text file, else simply ignore it, this one I did like as below..

cat /inputfolder_path/lookup_filename.txt | awk '{IGNORECASE = 1;line=$0;split(line,a, "~") ;if (a[1] ~ /201404/ && a[3]~/Cluster/ && a[4]~/WEEK/ && a[5]~/8.2/){print $0}}' > /outputfolder_path/derived_output_filename.txt

this is working exactly for my requirement..

Just thought to update this to every one, as it may help someone..

Thanks,
Siva

Comment: Useless Use Of Cat, incorrect placement of IGNORECASE, unnecessary duplication of fields array, useless use of split(), no anchors for REs, unnecessary explicit print command, and you've re-introduced your original bug of treating `.` in an RE as a literal char. That is an excellent example of a script that produces the output you want given a specific input file but is not a solution to the problem. Use the solution you were already given and enhance THAT if necessary, don't start over.

Comment: may be I can remove the cat and test, but awk is needed, because the string was a concatenated with "~"symbol in the source script. so we are looking the stings which have those values on a particular column after delimiting it. if I use grep int this place, it would bring the result if "cluster" is available at anywhere in the line.. 

probably there may be an alternate to tune, which I dont know as a newbie.. thank you Ed Morton,

Comment: Several people went to great lengths to explain whey you can't simply use `.` in `8.2` and yet here you are using it again, and you already know that awk automatically splits lines into fields yet here you are calling split() to do it explicitly. You never need grep with awk. etc. etc. I'm just saying - read the posts you were provided and THINK about it.